# Regex for double quoted and non double quoted string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse parameters of a CLI command and the input can be something like,

1. `"system console" 44` (can have spaces between double quotes)
2. `system 45` (If the first param doesn't have double quotes, it cannot have spaces i.e `system`)

I tried building regex for the input pattern as shown in point 1 - `("[^"]*")\s*(\d*)`

However this regex only works for the input #1. I'm trying to build a regex which would work for both the above inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In your first group, alternate with word characters (or non-space characters):

```
("[^"]*"|\w+)\s*(\d*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/01RRu3/1